# How to change the image in a cocos2d sprite from an array?

Tags: iphone, image, cocos2d-iphone, sprite

I'm trying to change the image that a sprite from an array is displaying. Here is the code I'm using:

```
((Sprite *)[enemiesArray objectAtIndex:index]).image = baseImage;
```

I get the error message:

```
error: request for member 'image' in something not a structure or union
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that this is the way to do this.
Rather than that you should call one of the init methods:

- (id) initWithCGImage:(CGImageRef)image;

- (id) initWithTexture:(Texture2D*) tex;

- (id) initWithFile:(NSString *) imageFile;

In my game i do this differently, i have a class for my object called 'Zed' which i also store in an array. It has a sprite as a field and if i want to change the image i swap the whole sprite and make sure i hide the old and show the new one.

Answer (score 1):

I do it like this:

```
Texture2D *texture = [[Texture2D alloc] initWithImage:myUIImage]
[sprite setTexture: texture];
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd better do it this way:

Somewhere in the init:

```
CCSpriteBatchNode *spritesheet = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"car_anim.png"];
[self addChild:spritesheet];

[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"car_anim.plist"];
```

Somewhere in action:

```
[yourSprite setDisplayFrame:[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:@"car_left.png"]];
```

*.plist and *.png could be done with Zwoptex.

Other solutions might break you animation when you are trying to change the texture while doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

[((Sprite *)[enemiesArray objectAtIndex:index]) setImage:baseImage];